# tkinter window checkbox operation

Tags: python, tkinter

My check box(admin_check) is not setting values in check_var while being toggled. When i remove root window it works fine but i can not remove since its necessary.

```
def c():
    print(check_var.get())


root=Tk()
#initially it must be minimised not to be open until login by user
root.quit() 
inst_window=Tk()


#instruction and login window

login_frame=Frame(inst_window,bg="lightpink",height=100,width=100)
check_var=StringVar()
admin_check=Checkbutton(login_frame,text="Adm",variable=check_var, onvalue='admin',offvalue='user',command=c)
login=Button(login_frame,text="login",command=c)
admin_check.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
login.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)

login_frame.pack()
login_frame.pack_propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first problem is that you can't call `Tk()` twice. Tkinter is designed to have exactly one instance of `Tk()`. There may be other problems, but until you fix that one there's not point in addressing any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Oakley mentioned, you cannot have two `Tk()`, Instead use `Toplevel()`

Change `inst_window=Tk()`

To `inst_window=Toplevel(root)`

Once you've done that, there are no other problems and the code works fine. You may also want to set the default of your checkbox to unselected, you can do this:

```
check_var.set("user")
```